# Derivative of a differential equation help??

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Please can someone explain this to me in detail: if $y''+4y'+3y=14\cos(2x)$ and $z'''+4z''+3z'=-28\sin(2x)$ show that the $z=y+c$ where $c$ is a constant I know the second is the integral of the first but I am not initially sure where the constants come from, please help?

Comment: Ever heard of constant of integration?

Comment: yes but i need to know exactly where it comes from and for some one to explain to me why z=y+c, i know where it comes from  intergration just not sure which part

Comment: Sorry I have changed it now

Comment: @Amzoti : I thought of doing it this way until I noticed the constants $c_1$ and $c_2$ are arbitrary meaning that $z = y+c$ is not always true as you can have different constants. Unless the OP states precise initial conditions then it is not generally true.

Comment: just a quick question on the side if g(x)=f(x) does g'(x)=f'(x) and visa versa if so why?

Comment: If the functions are equal, so are their derivatives. You can prove this using the definition of a derivative and going through the limit. Another way of proving it is to differentiate $f - g = 0$. The derivative of a sum is the sum of the derivative and the derivative of $0$ is $0$ ie $f' - g' = 0$ which in turn implies $f' = g'$.

Comment: The other way is wrong, you will get a constant being created. A quick way to notice it is to consider $f(x) = g(x) + c$. When differentiating wrt $x$, the constant will vanish (whatever the constant) and you obtain $f' = g'$. Another way of showing this is to consider the integrals : $f'(x) = g'(x)$ implies : $$\int_0^x f'(u) du = \int_0^x g'(u) du$$ which is the same as $f(x) - f(0) = g(x) - g(0)$ or after rearrangement you have $f(x) = g(x) + f(0) - g(0)$ where $f(0) - g(0)$ is your constant term.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not generally true as $$z(x) = e^{-3 x}+ 2e^{-x}+\frac{112}{65} \sin(2 x)-\frac{14}{65} \cos(2 x) + 1$$ is a solution as well as $$y(x) = e^{-3 x}+ e^{-x}+\frac{112}{65} \sin(2 x)-\frac{14}{65} \cos(2 x)$$

but in this case it appears that : $$z = y + e^{-x} + 1$$

The reason is that you haven't specified any initial conditions allowing me to set the arbitrary constants to be what I want.

$$z(x) = \frac{-C_1}{3}e^{-3 x} - C_2e^{-x}+\frac{112}{65} \sin(2 x)-\frac{14}{65} \cos(2 x) + C$$
is the general form of the solution, $y(x)$ being the same except the last constant $C$.
With $2$ initial conditions, you can fix the constants $C_1$ and $C_2$ so that they are the same and you answer follows.

Comment: If z=y+c are z's and y's general solutions do you get a constant from two places when solving (if by CF-PI from both the CF and the PI) this is what has occurred for me when doing it for a general expression

Comment: You get two arbitrary constants for the CF, namely $C_1$ and $C_2$ using my notation. The constant $C$ appears because to solve the second equation you actually solve for $z'$ so to obtain $z$, you need to integrate your solution once more giving this constant.